# LaTeXit alternative for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, latex

On my Mac I was using [LaTeXit](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/). It takes a LaTeX code and produces instant pdfs (or pngs, jpgs, etc…).

I'm sure there's a similar programme for Ubuntu. But I was unable to find one.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Markus.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "Linux latex editors"? You will find there are many, including `texmaker` for example. Personally, I do all my LaTeX stuff with `emacs`.

Answer (score 14):

The equivalent application *should be* [KLatexFormula](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net/), which can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install klatexformula
```

**But** if you have a recent enough Ubuntu, the current version (3.2.7) [triggers a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/klatexformula/bugs/13/) that makes it unusable, which is fixed in 3.2.8, but it is not available at this date.

You can probably compile it from source [following the instructions](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net/klfwiki/index.php/User_Manual%3aDownloading_&_Installing#Install_instructions_-_Compiling_From_Source), I have not tried.

I have submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/klatexformula/+bug/1296902).

UPDATE --- there is already (two hour after the filing of the bug!) a fix filed  for Trusty that should fix the problem. Thanks to the developer.

Comment: Very good! I think I have a lot to look forward to when it comes to Trusty.

Comment: There is an SRU request for 13.10 too --- should hopefully go to updates shortly.

Comment: Strange. I'm using 14.04 now and another bug is troubeling me: GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely recommend [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) for this. From the 2.1 release, LyX contains an ["equation editor" mode](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX21#cropped) that can generate similar output as [KLatexFormula](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net/) or [Ekee](http://rlehy.free.fr/).

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completion, a few more LateX equation editors:

- [EqualX](http://equalx.sourceforge.net/) - GPL3, WYSIWYG, installable from [a deb package](http://equalx.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).
- [Laeqed](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/) - LaTeX equation editor specifically targeted at producing PNG images of math equations for use on web pages. Java based, you can either download the jar file or run it [directly in your browser](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/laeqed.jnlp).
- [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) - PHP based WYSIWYG equation editor accessible with a web browser, no need to install software. Export to several different image formats including vectors.
- [TeXMaths](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/texmaths-1) - an extension to LibreOffice, only recommended if you use this office suite.

Comment: +1 --- the online LaTeX equation editor is really handy.

Comment: I like EqualX too. It's a shame it isn't in the (official) repositories.

Comment: @Markus EqualX is in the official repositories *now*.